# Inline Translation Not Working

Tags: magento-enterprise, csv, localisation, inline

Went to try and do some inline translations for a german store view I set up. I made a french store view at the same time.

While new to inline translations, I translated a block of text in the german store view last week to show test text.

When I go back to the german store view to enter the actual translated text, the block is no longer editable/translatable.. There is no red box around it with an option to select it for translation.

If I go to the french store view that has the same block at the footer, it is readily available for translation.

--

Because the native english text for that block was already 'translated' to display test content, does this mean once you inline translate (or enter any text) something, you can't translate it again to different text?

How can I get around this? Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Inline translation is enabled on a per-store view basis. In your case, it seems like it is enabled for French store view and is not enabled for German store view. You can enable it as usual, at `System > Configuration > Advanced > Developer >  Translate Inline` and select *German* store view in  *Configuration scope* dropbox at top left corner. Do not forget to flush cache at `System > Cache Management` to apply changes.